# Internet access not available in terminal Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

Actually, I can install updates, however, when I try to access an url e.g. wget --spider http://www.google.co.in, or downloading https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-lib/archive/refs/tags/v1.16.3.tar.gz - the access times out.  I can access these locations from within a browser.  I am running a corporate VPN but the http://www.google.co.in access is refused whether VPN is active or not.

Comment: You may want to bring this up with the Company IT they may be the problem.

Comment: I don't think IT has a hand in this.  Does anyone know of a configuration setting that would restrict terminal access to the internet?